# pip install geos or basemap - fail to install

Tags: python, pandas, pip, matplotlib-basemap, geos

Can anyone help please, I'm trying to install geos and basemap in jupyter notebooks but getting the same error for both.

Selections of output posted below.

```
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [93 lines of output]

      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

Comment: "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?" - what don't you understand?

Comment: "Perhaps try: xcode-select --install" - did you try that?

Comment: I just don't understand what I need to do now to enable Jupiter Labs to install basemap and geos. I'm not very good at handling error messages such as this, I have seen it before when trying to install a reader and never figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Try installing(If ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
```

Then

```
pip install lxml
```

> or

If windows [check this](https://pypi.org/project/libxml2-python3/)

```
pip install libxml2-python3
```

Then

```
conda install lxml
```

Finally your requirement

```
pip install geos
```

Comment: In terminal on Mac, the following error appears. sudo: apt-get: command not found. When adding sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev

Comment: @Tez apt-get will not work on your Mac, apt is the package manager of Debian-based GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what will work on mac to get this fixed pls?